# How do change address YiiFramework pagination?

Tags: yii

Default pagination in yii FrameWork for next pages:

`www.example.com/articles/?article_page=2`

how do change this Address "?article_page=2"  to only "page2":

`www.example.com/article/page2`

Answer (score 0):

Yii has a built in feature called urlManager located in 'config\main.php' uncomment the code below.

```
/*
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
    */
```

This link should help you clean up the url.  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url